# How do I write SQL to get objects

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL table called persons

```
id  LastName    FirstName
1       Hansen      Timoteivn
2       Svendson    Tove
3       Pettersen   Kari
```

and another MySQL table called orders.

```
id  OrderNo  personID
1       77895    3
2       44678    3
3       22456    1
4       24562    1
5       34764    15
```

How can I write a SQL query that I feed into PHP's `mysql_query()` function to return a list of "Order objects" that each contain a "Person object?" Each "Person object" has first name and last name as properties.

Comment: SQL doesn't give you objects. Ever.

Comment: Is there a way one could use `mysql_fetch_object()` to produce an object with objects from a resource returned by a SQL query?

Comment: you want to use that object for showing in front end screen only . right ?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to iterate through an array of Order objects, and list order numbers next to the first and last names of persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query will return orders by a certain person (*this will not give the object*)

```
SELECT a.ID, a. FirstName, a.LastName, b.OrderNo
FROM Persons a INNER JOIN Orders b ON
        a.ID = b.PersonID
WHERE a.ID = 1
```